# Events in R EHA

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

I prepared a data set to perform an event history analysis. When I do a count of the number of events,

```
 > event_info[, .(sum(event))]
 V1
 1: 4102
```

When I run,

```
library(eha)
reliability <- aftreg(Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~ 1, 
                dist = "weibull", data = event_info)
summary(reliability)
```

I get,

```
Call:
aftreg(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~ 1, data = event_info, 
    dist = "weibull")

Covariate          W.mean      Coef Time-Accn  se(Coef)    Wald p
Baseline parameters:
log(scale)                   11.975 158696.930     0.086     0.000 
log(shape)                   -0.978     0.376     0.025     0.000 
Baseline life expectancy:  

Events                    1541 
Total time at risk        68581432 
Max. log. likelihood      -16890
```

I don't understand why the events count is different from the count in the event_info data set.

Unfortunately I cannot post the data.

Can someone shed light on how events are counted in eha